# Find Values in Object Array from a List

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, lodash

I have an object array that looks like this:

UserForm

```
{ 
name:"Tom",
occupation:"Programmer",
hobbies:" ",
foodAllergy:"fish",
favoriteColor:"blue" 
}
```

And an `ValidateFieldsArray` that looks like this:

```
["hobbies", "foodAllergy", "name"]
```

I need to validate that there are strings filled in from the `ValidateFieldsArray` in the `UserForm` object array. It would return false because `hobbies` is empty.

Currently I'm using a For loop to traverse through the validateFieldsArray and it works fine. I'm wondering if there is a better solution. I also `trim` the string.

I can't use lodash because I'm comparing the key not the value. I want to do something like this and add additional checks like string.trim() !=="":

```
 _.result(_.find(UserForm, { key in ValidateFieldsArray}), value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.every` seems more appropriate to check every key in an array

```
var isValid = ValidateFieldsArray.every( v => UserForm[v] && UserForm[v].trim().length);
```

Comment: Is the length check on the string necessary? Empty string is falsy. Still better than mine.

Comment: @JaredSmith - no, the `length` check probably isn't neccessary

Answer (score 3):

```
let isValid = validateFieldsArray.reduce((obj, k) => {
  return (obj && obj[k].trim()) ? obj : false;
}, UserForm);
```

Returns the `UserForm` object if valid otherwise returns boolean `false`. Object must have a string that has more than just whitespace. If you replace `let` with `var` and the arrow function then the code is valid ES 5 and works back to IE 9.